# Автопрокрутка RecycleView. Странное поведение

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

есть проект примерно со слеюущей структурой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все это находится во ViewPager как одна из вкладок.
Проблема в том что при переключении на этот фрагмент верхняя граница RecyclerView оказывается сверху экрана,а Relative layout уходит наверх вне зоны видимости. В чем может быть проблема?  мне хотелось бы чтобы фрагмент открывался с самого верха.

Comment: Когда-то было такое. Не помню точно, но вроде нужно `RecyclerView` поставить `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` и убрать `behavior`.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` для `RecyclerView`

Comment: Ничего из этого не помогло

Comment: @Алексей, тогда показывайте разметку и поясняйте как оно должно выглядеть. А то по вашей картинке я три разных поведения могу сходу предложить совершенно разных

Comment: mRecyclerView.setFoucsable(false) решил проблему. Спасибо за подсказку направления, что это из-за фокуса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавив mRecyclerView.setFoucsable(false). Всем спасибо